# How to display one Observable of an Observable-Array in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have an Observable-Array which contains a list of questions. I would like to display my questions one by one but can't figure out a way to do that.

So far I only managed to display all of them with a *ngFor in my html.

This is my component:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { mergeMap, Observable, of, concatAll, Subject, startWith, zip, Subscription } from "rxjs";
import { Question } from "../models/Question";
import { QuestionService } from "../services/question.service";
import { AuthService } from "../services/auth.service";
import { User } from "../models/User";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-play',
  templateUrl: './play.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./play.component.css']
})
export class PlayComponent implements OnInit {

  user_id: Pick<User, "id"> | undefined
  unanswered_questions$: Observable<Question[]> | undefined
  question$: Observable<Question> | undefined

  constructor(
    private questionService: QuestionService,
    private authService: AuthService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.user_id = this.authService.userId
    this.unanswered_questions$ = this.getUnansweredQuestions(this.user_id)
  }

  getUnansweredQuestions(user_id: Pick<User, "id"> | undefined):    Observable<Question[]> {
    return this.questionService.fetchAllUnansweredQuestions(user_id);
  }
}
```

This is my html:

```html
<mat-card class="question-card" *ngFor="let question of unanswered_questions$ | async">
  <mat-card-header>
    <div mat-card-avatar class="example-header-image"></div>
    <mat-card-title>{{question.title}}</mat-card-title>
  </mat-card-header>
  <mat-card-content>
    <h3>{{question.body}}</h3>
  </mat-card-content>
  <mat-card-actions>
    <button mat-button>{{question.answer1}}</button>
    <button mat-button>{{question.answer2}}</button>
    <button mat-raised-button color="accent">Skip<mat-icon>skip_next</mat-icon></button>
  </mat-card-actions>
</mat-card>
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46029433/how-to-display-one-value-of-observableany-in-angular-template-until-next-cli) Post where someone is trying to do basically the same thing. Unfortunately both answers on that post don't work for me. I figured that they don't work due to the post being 4 years old and me using a newer version of rxjs and angular.

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: When you say "display one by one" what does this mean? What have you tried so far to achieve the desired functionality?

Comment: My observable-Array unanswered_questions$ contains multiple questions that I want to show to my user one by one, so the user can press the skip button and the next question will be displayed.

So far I have tried both solutions from the post I linked in my question. I've tried to subscribe to my observable and somehow get the data from the observable-array to be saved in a normal observable (question$: Observable<Question> | undefined). Unfortunately this does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you code "works" because you are piping your observable to the async pipe handler which holds executing the ngFor until the observable is resolved.

I would alter your code so that you subscribe to the observable and handle the  ensuing result. Actually, I would first convert to a promise and await it since, IMO, that style is more readable and predictable, especially for a "one and done" event.

So alter your component like so (NOTE: I've left off the imports and decorator for sake of brevity):

```
export class PlayComponent implements OnInit {

  user_id: Pick<User, "id"> | undefined;
  unanswered_questions: Question[];
  question$: Observable<Question> | undefined;
  questionIndex = 0;

  constructor(
    private questionService: QuestionService,
    private authService: AuthService
  ) { }

  async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
    this.user_id = this.authService.userId;
    await this.unanswered_questions = this.getUnansweredQuestions(this.user_id).toPromise();
  }

  getUnansweredQuestions(user_id: Pick<User, "id"> | undefined):    Observable<Question[]> {
    return this.questionService.fetchAllUnansweredQuestions(user_id);
  }

  skipQuestion(): void {
    if (this.questionIndex !== this.getUnansweredQuestions.length) {
     this.questionIndex++;
     }
  }
}
```

And then your HTML:

```
<mat-card class="question-card" *ngIf="unanswered_questions">
  <mat-card-header>
    <div mat-card-avatar class="example-header-image"></div>
    <mat-card-title>{{unanswered_questions[questionIndex].title}}</mat-card-title>
  </mat-card-header>
  <mat-card-content>
    <h3>{{unanswered_questions[questionIndex].body}}</h3>
  </mat-card-content>
  <mat-card-actions>
    <button mat-button>{{unanswered_questions[questionIndex].answer1}}</button>
    <button mat-button>{{unanswered_questions[questionIndex].answer2}}</button>
    <button mat-raised-button color="accent" (click)="skipQuestion()">Skip<mat-icon>skip_next</mat-icon></button>
  </mat-card-actions>
</mat-card>
```

By adding ngIf to your matCard you prevent rendering until the observable is resolved.

Comment: Thank you for your response! This worked perfectly for what I'm trying to do. I just had to use `this.unanswered_questions = await lastValueFrom(this.getUnansweredQuestions(this.user_id));` since `toPromise()` is deprecated, but other than that, this seems like a perfect solution, thank you!